# is there any deep level of host redirection in HttpClient 4.3.6?

Tags: java, redirect, apache-httpclient-4.x

Writing an API in JAVA to scrape the site which redirects to multiple host before delivering the required page. 
for ex 
** Main Host **
www.abc.com

**First redirection from Main Host url response**
www.pqr.com/test?a=1&b=2

**Second redirection from first redirection response**
www.xzy.com/result?sum=3

HttpClient works flawlessly upto the first redirection it also gets correct response but program redirects to 
**www.pqr.com/result?sum=3**
which gives me 404 :(

So, is there any deep level of redirection in httpclient? or am I missing something?
Network traffic monitored by using the fiddler. Application is written in JAVA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup maximum number of redirections when building client object via `RequestConfig.builder.setMaxRedirects(int maxRedirects)` ([see docs](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig.Builder.html)).

But by default this number is equal to `50` which obviously greater then number of redirects needed in your case. That means that problem lies somewhere else and without viewing your code or exact name of initial host you are connecting to, it is impossible to find reason of the problem.